# Finding max in min heap

Tags: java, algorithm

I was studying for an exam and from one of the worksheets I was looking over, it asks to write a method largest() for min heap that stores integers.

```
public class Heap {
   private int[] arr = new int[100];
   private int numElts = 0;

   public int largest(){

  }

}
```

the max size is 100 elements and newElt keeps track of the current number of elements stored in the heap.

I was thinking of doing something like :

```
int[] newArr = Collections.sort(arr);
return newArr[newElt];
```

but then that would change the original heap.
I could make a deep copy of it but it says it is not necessary for it to examine all of the heap's element.

So can anyone suggest a way to do this without looking at every single element?
Thanks,

Comment: I could keep track of max when adding but if it asks me to write largest() on an exam, I can't just write an add or insert :P

Answer (score 3):

If your structure is in heap order, if it was a -max heap- then your max element would simply be `arr[0]`. But because it's a min heap, all you know is that the max element is a leaf node.

So you don't need to test -every- element. But you will need to look at at most half of the elements (as for a binary tree, the number of leaves is between 1 and half the size plus one, inclusive on both accounts).

You can shortcut looking at leaf nodes by knowing that a binary heap (which you describe) is a special **balanced** binary tree, which with a small calculation can tell you where the two sets of leaf nodes might be.

Comment: Spelling it out completely: you only need to look at leaf nodes, because every non-leaf node is, by definition, smaller than its (1 or 2) children, and thus cannot be maximal.

Comment: Oh I think I see. So I could just look at the second half of the array ((newElts-1)/2 to newElts) which will be all leaf nodes right?

Comment: @TKP I believe that's correct, but I confess it has been a while since I worked with that kind of stuff. :)